# Find the Fourier cosine transform of the function defined by $f(x)= \frac1{1+x^2}$

Tags: fourier-transform

Don't know how to answer this question.
please give the answer if anyone knows..
I am using this equation
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int^\infty_0 f(x) \cos (\omega x)  \,dx
\end{align}

Comment: Jacky Chong, give any contact details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $F(\omega)$ be represented by the integral

$$F(\omega)=\sqrt{\frac 2\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(\omega x)}{1+x^2}\,dx\tag1$$

Next, given that $\int_0^\infty \frac{x\sin(\omega x)}{1+x^2}\,dx$ converges uniformly for $\omega\ge \omega_0>0$ then

$$\begin{align}
F'(\omega)&=-\sqrt{\frac 2\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{x\sin(\omega x)}{1+x^2}\,dx\\\\
&=-\sqrt{\frac 2\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{(1+x^2-1)\sin(\omega x)}{x(1+x^2)}\,dx\\\\
&=-\sqrt{\frac 2\pi}\left(\frac\pi 2 -\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(\omega x)}{x(1+x^2)}\right)\,dx\tag 2
\end{align}$$

And owing to uniform convergence again, we assert that

$$\begin{align}
F''(\omega)&=\sqrt{\frac 2\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(\omega x)}{1+x^2}\,dx\\\\
&=F(\omega)\tag3
\end{align}$$

Solving the ODE in $(3)$ yields

$$F(\omega)=Ae^{\omega}+Be^{-\omega} \tag 4$$

Now, letting $\omega \to 0$ in $(1)$ and $(2)$ reveals that $F(0)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2} }$ and $F'(0)=-\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$.

Applying these initial conditions to $(4)$ yields

$$F(\omega)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-|\omega|}$$

And we are done!

Comment: but the eqn used is incorrect..

Comment: i have given the right eqn

Comment: @Arun Yes, I've edited the solution to correct the typo.

Comment: is this correct

Comment: Yes, it is indeed.

Comment: give any contact detail of u

Comment: My contact detail is on my user page.  And here is the [WA result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(2%2Fpi)+integral+cos(+w+x)+%2F(1%2Bx%5E2)+dx+from+0+to+infinity).  -Mark

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Observe $f(x) = (1+x^2)^{-1}$ is even, which means
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0 f(x)\cos \omega x\ dx =&\ \frac{1}{2}\int^\infty_{-\infty} f(x)\cos\omega x\ dx 
=\ \frac{1}{2}\int^\infty_{-\infty} f(x)\frac{e^{i\omega x}+e^{-i\omega x}}{2}\ dx\\
 =&\ \frac{1}{4}\int^\infty_{-\infty} f(x)e^{i\omega x}\ dx+\frac{1}{4}\int^\infty_{-\infty}f(x)e^{-i\omega x}\ dx= \frac{1}{2}\int^\infty_{-\infty} f(x) e^{-i\omega x}\ dx.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

A hint: You have seen Dr. MV's answer. If you are not convinced compute the Fourier transform of $F(\omega):=\sqrt{\pi/2}\>e^{-|\omega|}$. You should obtain the given $f(x)$.