# Solving given improper integral

Tags: integration, analysis, improper-integrals

Unfortunately, I forgot how to solve the following improper integral.

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos{x}}{x^2+4}\;dx
\end{equation}

Could you give some hints?

Comment: Contour integration of $e^{iz}/(z^2+4)$ over the usual semicircle.

Comment: Your integral is a special case of this one (set $a=2$): [Computing $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{x^{2} + a^{2}}dx$ using residue calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140580/computing-int-infty-infty-frac-cos-xx2-a2dx-using-residue)

Comment: the result should be $$\frac{\pi}{2e^2}$$

Comment: @Sonnhard thanks for providing this unique new information

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Let $I(a)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2+4}\,dx$ and show ([See This Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2236261/find-the-fourier-cosine-transform-of-the-function-defined-by-displaystyle-fx/2236287#2236287), [and This One](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372949/evaluate-the-integral-int-limits-infty-infty-frac-cosxx21dx/2373711#2373711)) that $I''(a)=4I(a)$ along with $I(0)=\pi/2$ and $I'(0)=-\pi$.

Find $I(a)$ as solution of the ODE and initial conditions then set $a=1$.

Comment: How did you get $I''(a)=I(a)$?

Comment: @xpaul Thank you for catching the typo.... $I''(a)=4I(a)\ne I(a)$ ... I've edited.

Comment: @captain23 Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: Note $I''(a)$ diverges.

Comment: @xpaul No, $I''(a)$ does not diverge!  $I(a)$ is clearly twice differentiable inasmuch as $I(a)=\frac\pi2 e^{-2a}$.  To find $I''(a)$, one cannot simply interchange the integral with the second derivative.  Read the answers in the links.

Comment: $I''(a)=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2\cos(ax)}{x^2+4}\,dx$ diverges.

Comment: @xpaul Read the answers in the links!  Note $$I''(a)\ne \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^2\cos(ax)}{x^2+4}\,dx$$Why do you insist on nonsense?

Comment: @xpaul Have you read the answers in the links yet?  If so, do they resolve your issue?

Comment: I see now in the link.

Comment: @xpaul So,.was this answer and the ones in the link not useful to you then?

Comment: Yes, it is very useful.

Comment: @xpaul Pleased to hear.  And feel free to up vote answers as you see fit.  ;-)